# Google Tag Manager: Extract Last Part of URL

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am aware that there are other questions/answers on this topic, but my question has a little twist.

I need to create a Google Tag Manager variable that extracts the last part of a URL.

Here's an example of a URL:
https://legendautosales.com/vehicle-details/used-2015-lexus-ct-200h-hybrid-JTHKD5BHXF2219976

The format of the URL is **not** consistent, since some vehicles have extra features and details that add extra parameters to the URL. I can say that that last part of the URL always has 17 characters (it's the VIN). So is there a way to tell GTM to just extract the last 17 characters of a URL?

Thanks very much in advance for your help - I'm a total JavaScript beginner.

Comment: try slicing it with `str.slice(-17)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "extra parameters" you mean query parameters, then simply work on the Page Path variable instead of Page Url. Page Path does not contain query parameters.

If you mean it adds extra elements to the path, then [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the Page Path variable by the delimiter "/", which gives an array, and call the [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method on that array, which gives you the last element. Do that in a custom Javascript variable and return the result of array.pop().